# Displaying list of image URLS from Parse.com with recyclerView and Glide library

Tags: android, android-studio, parse-platform, android-recyclerview, android-glide

So basically the code doesn't generate any error, but my screen goes blank everytime i try to run it. can someone please check my code below.

I think i messed up the recyclerView Adapter?

**THIS IS MY Recycler Adapter**

```
public class recylerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<recylerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    List<ImageUrl> data;
    private Context context;

    public recylerAdapter(Context context,List<ImageUrl> data){

        inflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.data=data;
        this.context=context;

    }

    @Override
    public recylerAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, parent, false);

        ViewHolder holder= new ViewHolder(view);

        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final recylerAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        ImageUrl current= data.get(position);

        Glide.with(context)
                .load(current.Url)
                .override(100,100)
                .into(holder.imageView);


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        ImageView imageView;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            imageView=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        }
    }
}
```

**This is the mainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


  private recylerAdapter adapter;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpenedInBackground(getIntent());

    RecyclerView recyclerView=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    adapter= new recylerAdapter(this,getData());

    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));


  }

 public static List<ImageUrl> getData(){

   final List<ImageUrl> data= new ArrayList<>();

   ParseQuery<ParseObject>query= ParseQuery.getQuery("TestObject");

     query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
         @Override
         public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
             if (e==null && objects.size()>0){
                 for (ParseObject object:objects){
                     ParseFile file= object.getParseFile("image");

                     ImageUrl current= new ImageUrl();

                     current.Url=file.getUrl();

                     data.add(current);

                 }
             }
         }
     });

return data;
 }



  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
      return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }
}
```

thi**s is my POJO class for recyclerView Data**

public class ImageUrl {

public String Url;

}

Comment: Maybe your list is empty when you're setting the adapter. Try setting the adapter on the recyclerview when you get the callback in the done method.

Comment: Yes, it worked. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

`findInBaackground` is an **asynchronous** method which means that you will not have the result instantaneously when the method returns but you have to wait. This is the goal of the `FindCallBack`: its `done` method is called when the result is available.

Your mistake is that you use the content of the `data` list just after the `findInBackground` returns but it's obviously empty!

What you can do is to replace your `getData` method with the following

```
public void loadData(){
 final List<ImageUrl> data = new ArrayList<>();
 ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("TestObject");
 query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
     @Override
     public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
         if (e==null && objects.size()>0){
             for (ParseObject object:objects){
                 ParseFile file= object.getParseFile("image");
                 ImageUrl current= new ImageUrl();
                 current.Url=file.getUrl();
                 data.add(current);
             }
             adapter = new recylerAdapter(MainActivity.this, data);
             recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
         }
     }
 });
}
```

And your onCreate:

```
private RecyclerView recyclerView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpenedInBackground(getIntent());

      recyclerView=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
      recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
      recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

      loadData();
}
```

To improve the UX you should add a ProgressBar or just a "Loading" text to alert the user that the data is loading. In the `done` callback you can stop the loading and the data are visible to the user

Comment: it worked really well!!. thank you so much. i was being careless

Comment: Can you elaborate this statement that you gave me :                                      " Your mistake is that you use the content of the data list just after the findInBackground returns but it's obviously empty! "   i don't really get it because in my MAIN ACTIVITY  at the bottom of getData method, i put return data isn't that mean the ' data' is filled with content?